# Installing Flex 4.6 in Eclipse on Windows Vista

Tags: apache-flex, eclipse-plugin, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

I am using `Windows Vista 32bit`. I have installed `Eclipse Helios Service Release 2`.

I need to integrate `flex` in `Eclipse`. Can someone show give me steps to install or point me to a good tutorial that explains the process.

Note: I have downloaded `flex_sdk_4.6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments it seems FlashBuilder is your tool of choice.

**Download it**

Go to the [FlashBuilder download page](https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=flash_builder) to get it. The automatic download will have you download an Akamai software, which is Adobe's download crapware. If you're behind a proxy, you're out of luck: your download won't work. You can get a direct link though: simply cancel the automatic download and on the download page select the "File 1 of 1" link.

[image]

**Install it**

You can find the installation instructions here for both a standalone installation or as an Eclipse plugin: http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-builder/release-note/flash-builder-4-6-release.html#main_Install_your_software

Answer (score 1):

You can't really integrate Flex into eclipse without a plug-in - it would let you edit the text files as text, and run the compiler, but you'd have no actual IDE support.

As for plugins/eclipse-based IDEs: Right now, there's [Adobe Flash Builder](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-builder.html) and [FDT](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/), which are both good products (they each have different advantages and shortcomings, though -you probably want to try them out and see which fits your needs best), but they are both neither free nor cheap.

Another very good commercial IDE is [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), but that's not eclipse-based.

If you need a free IDE for ActionScript on Windows, check out [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/) - it is not quite as sophisticated as the eclipse-based commercial products, but a good start if you want to get into ActionScript, or try out IDE alternatives to Flash.

Comment: I did download Adobe Flash Builder and after installing the exe file i got a UI which is called `Akamai NetSession Interface console`. Now what should i do ? How can i get the flex Eclipse like IDE to open ?

Comment: Sure you downloaded this: https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=flash_builder ?

Comment: @weltraumpirat That Akamai thing is Adobe's download crapware. Here's a [direct link](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/bundle.cfm?loc=en_us&product=flash_builder_EN_US&urls=http://trials3.adobe.com/AdobeProducts/FLBR/4_6/win32/FlashBuilder_4_6_LS10.exe&language=en&index=0&name=Adobe%20Flash%20Builder%204.6%20English%20Windows&prompt=prompt&prdLabel=Adobe%20Flash%20Builder%204.6&optvalue=3_FS0002298_http%3A%2F%2Ftrials2.adobe.com%2FAdobeProducts%2FFLBR%2F4_6%2Fwin32%2FFlashBuilder_4_6_LS10.exe&upsell=#). You can get it if you cancel the automatic download.